# Query an Excel 2013 pivot table using an OLEDB connection and convert it to a C# DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have the following code that selects everything from a sheet in an Excel workbook that contains 3 pivot tables.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + spreadsheetLocation + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;'";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]";
OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, objConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt);
```

However, instead of selecting the whole sheet, I'd like to select the individual pivot tables as needed. Each pivot table has a name (currently PivotTable1, PivotTable2, and PivotTable3). I'm hoping there is something like:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [PivotTable1]";
```

But I can't get anything to work.  I don't want to depend on the pivot tables being in specific locations on the sheet. The Excel document is being uploaded by a standard user and its format is out of my control.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to change connection string to enable headers (HDR=yes)?

Answer (score 0):

The same functionality as PivotTable in MS Excel gives you [TRANSFORM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statement for OleDb, which is equivalent for PIVOT in SQL.
If you want to fetch data from different workbooks, please have a look at this tip on CP: [How to: Get Data from Multiple Workbooks using One OleDbConnection?](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/702769/How-to-Get-Data-from-Multiple-Workbooks-using-One)